# Scroll Bouncing With Fixed Positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed element that attaches on my page when you reach it in the scroll. This element can sometimes have content above it but not below it, meaning the page depth might not be deep enough to support this kind of behavior, because of this it prevents the user from reaching the bottom of the page and causes the page to bounce, presumably because it's removing the element from the scroll when it fixes, which causes the condition in the scroll event function to no longer be true. The gif shows the undesired effect when this happens.

[image]

Demonstrated here in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dcsjx625/8/

The pages are dynamic so removing the effect for a single page is not possible.

```
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x401">
  </div>
  <div class="content-parent">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-content">
  Footer
  </div>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
var $stickyChainOffset = $('.content').offset();
var $stickyChain = $('.content');
var $fixedWidth = $('.content').parent().width();

function checkScroll() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $stickyChainOffset.top - 100) {
    $stickyChain.css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '100px').css('max-width', $fixedWidth);
  } else {
    $stickyChain.css('position', 'static').css('max-width', 'initial');
  }
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
  checkScroll();
});

/* Updates the $fixedWidth variable on resize */
$(window).resize(function() {
  $fixedWidth = $('.content').parent().width();
  $(window).scroll();
});
```

Ideally I want to prevent the sticking effect if the element is close enough to the bottom of the page that it might cause a problem.

I've tried calculating the page depth vs the element height in the `checkScroll()` function like so but even this isn't working. I feel like I'm right on the edge of solving this.:

```
function checkScroll() {
  height = $stickyChain.height() + 100;
  depth = $(document).height() - $stickyChainOffset.top;

  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $stickyChainOffset.top - 100 && depth > height) {
    $stickyChain.css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '100px').css('max-width', $fixedWidth);
  } else {
    $stickyChain.css('position', 'static').css('max-width', 'initial');
  }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by preventing the sticky effect? I can't tell what the intended behavior of checkScroll() should be. Should it bounce to the top when you reach the bottom?

Comment: It should follow the user when they reach the element in the scroll, much like a header that attaches past the fold. The issue is that if the element doesn't have enough room when the if statement in checkScroll() is triggered (for example if the element is near the bottom of the page due to the content above it pushing it down) then it will cause the content to bounce, assuming because it's then triggering the else statement in checkScroll() immediately afterwards. It's a rare bug that occurs, but it happens and it looks strange.

Comment: I want the if statement to check to make sure that it can safely set the .content div to fixed without it causing this issue.

Comment: When you change the position of content to fix, the page scrolls to the top because the window is empty and  (fixed elements don't register a height in the body) that makes it jump, then "static" brings the scroll again at the very top. I still don't understand what the expected behavior is in order to suggest a solution. Do you have an example to illustrate the intended behavior?

Comment: I don't understand. No matter how I look at it the problem will always occur if the sticky element is at the bottom of the screen no matter how long the page is? The moment your user scroll to `$stickyChainOffset.top - 100` the sticky element is removed from the html flow, meaning the document's height is instantly reduced by the sticky element's height. Thus the total height of the document would be exactly `$stickyChainOffset.top`, `false`-ing the condition and putting the sticky element back to where it was before.

Comment: I don't want the element to be fixed if the page doesn't have enough depth to support the effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gotta be honest, I understand your problem but I have no idea when and why you'd run into this exact behavior. That said, here's my workaround and some notes:

1. The height of your content needs to be 2x the height of `fixed` element in order to maintain the scrollbar. Otherwise, once the element is `fixed`, your document entirely loses the scrollbar.
2. I'm saving the original offset of `fixed` element to a variable that is used as a marker for future reset. However, I am also redefining the `$stickyChainOffset` in every scroll event, that you used to define only once. I'm doing this because it changes once `fixed`.
3. You can comment and uncomment the padding I saved in `css` to see how the page behaves in various cases.

If you have any other questions, let me know.

https://jsfiddle.net/1fke1j3d/1/

Comment: This element sits in the right-rail of a website, where the left rail can sometimes be smaller than the right. The situation is rare but can occur. Ideally I want to calculate the height of the element, and how much scroll is left on the page, and then run a check in the scrollCheck() if statement which determines if the element can actually fix or not, and if doesn't have enough space, I want it to behave like a regular element.

Comment: Sorry, was just responding to your question regarding the situation. I will check now!

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I need. Thanks for solving that headache for me.